# Gap between last button an LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout, view, scrollview, android-linearlayout

My problem is that in my layout I have a big gap between the last element of my view (it´s a button) and the "bottom" of my view. 
I´m using a `LinearLayout` within a `ScrollView`. Where´s my mistake? I tried to set all padding to 0dp but there´s still the same issue.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="0dp"
tools:context=".MainMenu">

<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_ohne"

    >

       <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="126dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="seas"      
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btLineup"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/lineup"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btZumSpiel"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/wegweiserzumspiel"/>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btHighscore"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/highscore" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Do you want your view to be anchored to the bototm of the screen? it doesnt look like your view will be bigger than the screen to be able to be scrolled

Comment: Do you want the button with the name "btHighscore" that is your last button to be near to the bottom ?

Comment: I see my buttons on the top of the screen where they should be. After my last button there is a big gap where no element is.

Comment: Yes, it should be the last one

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code with the last button and notice this line **android:layout_marginTop="40dp"** now you can increase or decrease the value.

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/btHighscore"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"

                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/btnblue" />
```

Comment: With this code, the button moves down 40dp, but there is still the big gap between the button an the bottom..

Comment: then apply the background on the parent View that is scroll view not on the linear

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution:

Set

```
android:background
```

into the `ScrollView` tag an it works!